# Run time permission in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have created an app that can send message and make call(only if permission is granted)

I have tried it by manually allowing permission for accessing my SMS and Telephone to send SMS or make call using my phone settings

So this is my code (PhoneApp.java)

```
package com.example.phone;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PhoneApp extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
    private Toolbar mTopToolbar;
    private static final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;
    Button sendBtn;
    EditText txtMessage;
    EditText edittext1;
    Button button1;
    String phoneNo;
    String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myphone);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Getting the edittext and button instance
        edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        //Performing action on button click
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                makeCall();
            }



        });

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                        edittext1.getText().toString(),
                        null,
                        txtMessage.getText().toString(),
                        null,
                        null);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is not granted, requesting");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            sendBtn.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is granted");
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

    protected void makeCall() {
        String number=edittext1.getText().toString();
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PhoneApp.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PhoneApp.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_PHONE_CALL: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calling....",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission has been granted");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You can send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    sendBtn.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission has been denied or request cancelled");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    sendBtn.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

XML Code (myphone.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".PhoneApp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="@string/phone_number"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="109dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:hint="@string/type_your_message"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Send Sms" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="302dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
        android:text="Call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my design:

[image]

I want my app to ask permission only if I click on 'SEND SMS' button, instead my app asks permission every time I enter into the above page(without clicking on 'SEND SMS' button). But this is not in the case of button. It works perfectly(Asks permission only after I click on 'Call' button).

It would be nice if you help me solve this problem by providing solution in the form of snippet. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You ask for permissions to make a call in `makeCall`, which is called in event handler. You request SMS permissions in `onCreate` as opposed to event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple just change your onCreate() to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myphone);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Getting the edittext and button instance
    edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //Performing action on button click
    button1.setOnClickListener(this::makeCall());

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener((view) - >{
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is not granted, requesting");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
            },
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        } else {
            Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is granted");
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(
            edittext1.getText().toString(), null, txtMessage.getText().toString(), null, null);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem was that you were requesting permission for sending message in your onCreate() function but for it to work as you need you have to requesting permission from onClick() listener of your button.

Just on the topic I formatted your code by changing to lambda functions.

Hope this solves your problem. If you want I am happy to explain any part of the code I changed.